# State management - Cannot update a component (`Provider`) while rendering a different component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jotai

I am trying to use [jotai](https://github.com/pmndrs/jotai) to update a global indicator. The indicator will activate the [LinearProgress](https://mui.com/components/progress/)(true or false)

In **atom.js** I have created a basic atom that will serve as the indicator:

```
export const isDownloadAtom = atom(false)
```

Adding the provider to the app:

```
import { Provider } from "jotai";
ReactDOM.render(
<React.StrictMode>
    <Provider>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
</React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

And eventually updating the indicator:

```
import { Get } from 'react-axios';
import { useAtom } from "jotai";
import { isDownloadAtom } from "../store/atom";
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';


export default function Quotes() {

const [, set] = useAtom(isDownloadAtom)
const url = '/random'

return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Get url={url}>
            {(error, response, isLoading, makeRequest, axios) => {
                if (error) {
                    return (<div>Something bad happened: {error.message} <button onClick={() => makeRequest({ params: { reload: true } })}>Retry</button></div>)
                }
                else if (isLoading) {
                    set(true)
                    return (<div>Loading...</div>)
                }
                else if (response !== null) {
                    set(false)
                    return (
                        <div>
```

And the LinearProgress component:

```
  import { useAtom } from "jotai";
  import { isDownloadAtom } from "../../store/atom";
  export default function AppBar() {

  const [isDownload] = useAtom(isDownloadAtom)

  return (
    <div >
        <MuiAppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar variant="dense" color="inherit">
                <IconButton
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    aria-label="menu"
                    to="/"
                    component={Link}
                    size="large">
                    <IconHome />
                    <Typography variant="h6">Online Information</Typography>
                </IconButton>
            </Toolbar>
            {isDownload ? <LinearProgress /> : ''}
        </MuiAppBar>
    </div>
```

In general the code is working but when I **refreshing** the page (F5) I am getting the following warning message

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`AppBar`) while rendering a
> different component (`Request`). To locate the bad setState() call
> inside `Request

I would like to understand what is the issue and how can I resolved this.

Thank you

Comment: Check this out. It might help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030576/i-have-this-error-that-say-cannot-update-a-components-while-rendering-a-differe/67030659#67030659)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relation of AppBar and Quotes components? Are they siblings or one is rendered conditionally? Can't really tell without seeing the whole thing, but I assume `setState()` inside render block is the culprit. As a general rule, React component should not cause side effects in other components during rendering. Check if passing callbacks directly on `<Get>` component changes anything.

```
<Get url={url} onSuccess={(res) => set(false)} onLoading={() => set(true)}>
    {(error, response, isLoading, makeRequest, axios) => {
        if (error) {
            return (<div>Something bad happened: {error.message} <button onClick={() => makeRequest({ params: { reload: true } })}>Retry</button></div>)
        } else if (isLoading) {
            //set(true) - this is probably the issue
            return (<div>Loading...</div>)
        } else if (response !== null) {
            //set(false)
            return (<div>...
```

If you could provide a minimal reproducible example it would be much easier to tell what's going on.

Comment: Thank you Jacek for your answer and sorry for the missing info. The component are not siblings. They are both from different parts of the app. I am adding a link so you can see the relationship. https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-monad-iid61?file=/src/components/quote/ZenQuotes.jsx

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Without the endpoint i cant make sure its working but the snippet: ```<Get url={url} onSuccess={(res) => set(false)} onLoading={() => set(true)}>``` does get rid of bad state warning.

Comment: Yep, the URL is not working due to a proxy issue. At the end I decided to use Redux and I don't have any issues.  I think that your first suggestion (use callback) is the correct path to solve this. I just couldn't figure it out how to do that with jotai. Thank you very much for your help.